# How to update prices in jQuery calculator via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a "budget calculator" to manage money at festivals.

Can anyone tell me how you would include a PHP script within the JQuery?

So far I have the form calculating how much you may spend given your habits in different categories per day, then times it by 3 for the weekend.

I want to be able to update these prices as I go in order to make sure the price is as always as up to date as possible. So I created a mysql database and query that calculates the medium price and then returns it back to the page via a php script.

This is a JSfiddle to give you an idea of what it looks like at the moment - although it's not working on the site but you can see the set up.
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HavBZ/)
Here is a screen shot of what the form actually looks like. As you can see the price beside the title of each input is displayed via the php include. The button on the right leads to the "update" form that allows you to enter a new price.

[image: Screenshot]

This is an example of the query that is used to display calculate the medium:
PHP:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT x.price FROM price_pints x, price_pints y GROUP BY x.price HAVING SUM(     SIGN( 1 - SIGN( y.price - x.price ) ) ) / COUNT( * ) > .5 LIMIT 1"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "£".$row['price'];
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is get this same php include to work within the "data-unit-price" tag.. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is ... AJAX

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: this is the EASIEST way i come up with, i'm trying to avoid more advanced things like dynamically generated javascript or ajax

When you build the page (PHP, server-side), load the 3 prices in three variables and then have 3 hidden inputs like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="pint_price" value="<?php echo $pint_price; ?>">
```

your script should look at the hidden input's values to initialize the calculator.

NOTE: if the prices change while the page has already been loaded, the user does not see the update. you may want to consider putting a disclaimer somewhere.

The BEST solution would be to have an ajax request every time the user inserts a new value (if bandwith is not an issue, either for your server and for the user) or every X minutes.

See [jQuery get docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for reference and examples.

On an unrelated note, you really shouldn't be using mysql_* for interact with (MySQL) databases. Make a little effort and learn to use PDO. I really recommend it.

Comment: From what I've seen of the problem this is most likely the best approach anyway. AJAX would just be an unnecessary server call.